# Auto fill with bitwarden security question?

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-management

[image: Screenshot of my bitwarden autofill feature in action. Showing "Go to vault"]
Hi guys, 
I just started using bitwarden as a password manager and stumbled across a very confusing feature...
When I enable the password autofill feature (I know it's called auto fill..but still...) I don't even have to type in my password or fingerprint to go to my vault and see my password in plaintext or just login to the website... 
Is there a way of having autofill activated having to authenticate oneself before being able to view the password? This seems kind of counter productive to me

Comment: I don't use Bitwarden, but it should have a setting about this somewhere.

Comment: Ah, yes. I hat it set to "lock after 15 minutes" which I changed to "immediately" now I have to enter the PW or fingerprint to view it. My bad, didn't think of that before.